# jQuery - Add combinations to the string and repeat this for many input fields of a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cakephp-3.0

I have a form where I request a lot of data for a join table in cakePHP3.5 project. The string consists of combinations of factors A, B, C and D separated by space. For example: BD AC ABCD AD B CD. I found out how to compose this string for the one such field.

First I write a required combination to textbox `Result`, then use `Add` button to stitch them together.

How to repeat this for many without writing a long jQuery? Basically I need to repeat what is below 50 times, but I cannot find proper selectors for all these multiple checkboxes. Checkbox 1 down there is for illustrating purposes to emphasize that I will have different checkboxes and many such input fields.

This is my first jQuery, so please, be patient :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $('.factor-checkbox').click(function() {
    var text = $('#result0');
    text.val('');
    $(".factor-checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    text.val(text.val() + $(this).val());
    });
    
   
  });
    $("#btn0").click(function(){
    var text1 = $('#combinations0');
    text1.val(text1.val() + ' ' + $('#result0').val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="A" value="A" class="factor-checkbox">A</label>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="B" value="B" class="factor-checkbox">B</label>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="C" value="C" class="factor-checkbox">C</label>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="D" value="D" class="factor-checkbox">D</label>

<label for="result0">Result </label><input type="text" id="result0"/>

<button type="button" id="btn0">Add</button>

<div class="input checkbox"><label for="items-0-id"><input type="checkbox" name="items[0][id]" value="1" id="items-0-id">1</label></div>

<div class="input text"><label for="Combinations">Combinations</label><input type="text" id="combinations0"/></div>
```

Comment: If you are going to have many repetitions of "Result", then they cannot have all `id="result"`. How will the page look with two sets of checkboxes?

Comment: The second set will have result1, btn1, items-1-id and combinations1. I will edit the code to emphasize this, thank you.

Comment: I don't understand why you should have combinations1: shouldn't there just be one `combinations` which will have the result of all the repeated sections?

Comment: What is the purpose of the checkbox following the Add button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to:

- Wrap each repeating block (each with 4 checkboxes, ...etc) in a separate container element: that will facilitate to address the different elements that belong together.
- Don't use `id` attributes where not necessary: for labels you don't need them when you wrap the `input` inside the `label` element. Instead use `class` names. This will facilitate the generation of all the 50 blocks
- In each event handler determine the section the click happened in, and then use that as the scope of every other jQuery selection you do (by using the second argument of `$()` -- or `.find()`.

Here is working snippet with two such blocks:

```js
$(function() {
    function mapValues(elem) {
        return $(elem).val();
    }
    $(".factor-checkbox").click(function() {
        var $section = $(this).closest(".section");
        var $text = $(".result", $section);
        $text.val($.map($(".factor-checkbox:checked", $section), mapValues).join(""));
    });
    $(".add").click(function() {
        var $section = $(this).closest(".section");
        var $combi = $(".combinations", $section);
        $combi.val(($combi.val() + " " + $(".result", $section).val()).trim());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="A" value="A" class="factor-checkbox">A</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="B" value="B" class="factor-checkbox">B</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="C" value="C" class="factor-checkbox">C</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="D" value="D" class="factor-checkbox">D</label>

    <label>Result <input type="text" class="result"></label>

    <button type="button" class="add">Add</button>
    
    <div class="input text">
        <label>Combinations <input type="text" class="combinations"></label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="A" value="A" class="factor-checkbox">A</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="B" value="B" class="factor-checkbox">B</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="C" value="C" class="factor-checkbox">C</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="D" value="D" class="factor-checkbox">D</label>

    <label>Result <input type="text" class="result"></label>

    <button type="button" class="add">Add</button>

    <div class="input text">
        <label>Combinations <input type="text" class="combinations"></label>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this clarifies a lot and I think I will be able to get what is needed on the basis of your suggestion. I do need many fields Combinations and Add buttons. The end result which should be written to the table should look like this: [1] AB CD ABCD, [2] B DE AC, [3] ABC E BE, [4] A B C DE,....

Comment: How would combinations be removed again?

Comment: I updated the answer with the combination fields and add buttons. I hope I got what you intended as behaviour.

Comment: Not sure I understand. "Combinations" is a property of an item the user possesses. These strings will be stored in Items.Combinations. User can possess many items. The boxes "A, B, C, D, E", the field "Result" and the button "Add" are needed to make sure the user correctly composes this string. I am more inclined now to leave only one example on top and instruct the user to enter the string for all other items in a similar way. They should get an idea how the string is constructed.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!